# ¿Se ha llegado al extremo del Búfer?

Tags: json, excel, webservice, api

tengo el siguiente problema al enlazar un web service a una base de datos mysql con Excel haciendo uso de power query, apareciendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fijate si está dentro de los límites https://support.office.com/es-es/article/especificaciones-y-l%C3%ADmites-de-power-query-5fb2807c-1b16-4257-aa5b-6793f051a9f4?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES

Comment: Asi es, funciona en algunos computadores, en otros que ya se habian conectado antes simplemente no funcionan

Comment: el ecosistema microsoft suele ser muy interdependiente, versiones de sistemas operativos, versiones de excel versiones de los componentes etc... tendrías que ver una forma de aislar las variables y realizar algun tipo de debug para ver qué significa realmente el error: si se quedó sin memoria el proceso, si lo que guardó en el buffer está mal formado por x causa, etc...

Comment: si, es bastante extraño, no debería suceder de esa manera ya que con el power query de PowerBI funciona perfectamente. Intentaré realizar un debug haber que puedo encontrar.